# Why are all my templates in visual studio gone?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-mac

I recently installed Visual Studio for Mac 2022. I had VS Mac 2019, and it had the .net templates. When I installed VS 2022, all my previous .net templates were gone, even though I selected to install .net templates. When I open VS 2019, it has all of the templates installed, even the ones that I installed with only VS 2022. Is there any way to fix this, or should I just use VS 2019? [2022 vs 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGnal.png)

Comment: directory where templates are located is different. Just copy them.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try to set your .NET SDK path?

You can locate it under Preferences->SDK Locations->.NET Core and set the path as /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet.

Hope this can help solve the problem.

Ref: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Starter-templates-missing/10070338?space=41&q=missing+templates

Answer (score 0):

The Other - .NET project templates in Visual Studio for Mac 2019 require the Mono framework.

In Visual Studio for Mac 2022 the project templates that require Mono have been removed.

Instead you can install the [.NET SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download) use the project templates that target .NET 6.0, .NET Core 3.1, and these are available from the Web and Console section, if the associated SDKs are installed.

To install the .NET SDK you can either download them directly from the [download page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download) or re-run the installer and ensure that .NET is selected.